# New to Java - If - Else If issues

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm just learning Java and have become completely stumped with this bit of code. I've looked around, but part of the knowledge of languages is knowing the right questions to ask, and I've run out of ideas to search.  Everything looks ok to me, but I'm hoping a more experienced person will be able to educate me a little bit on this.

Whenever I run through this code, or step through, for temperatures from 100 to 213 (regardless of Celsius or Fahrenheit) the Else If will always run.  Can anyone enlighten me on why this is happening, or nudge me into the right frame of mind?  Here is the code:

```
package chapter.pkg3;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Chapter3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the temperature: ");
         double temp = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Please enter the temperature measurement, C or F: ");
         String measure = in.next();
     if (measure.equals("C"))
        { measure = "Celsius";}
     else 
        {measure = "Fahrenheit";}
     if ((temp <= 0 && measure.equals("C")) || (temp <= 32 && !measure.equals("C")))
        {
        System.out.print("The temperature is " + temp + " " + measure + ".  The water
        is freezing!");
        }
     if ((temp <= 100 && measure.equals("C")) || (temp <= 212 && !measure.equals("C")))
        {
        System.out.print("The temperature is " + temp +  " " + measure + ".  The water
        is liquid.");
        }
     if ((temp > 100 && measure.equals("C")) || (temp > 212 && !measure.equals("C")))
        {
        System.out.print("At " + temp + " " + measure + " the water has become gas.");
        }
  }
```

}

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: btw use equalsIgnoreCase() instead of equals()

Comment: check your codes properly. you have initialized measure = "Celcius" if user input "C". So The value of measure is "Celcius" not "C".

Comment: @gjman2 thanks for the advice, I didn't know about the equalsIgnoreCase() either.  Appreciate it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your `if` conditions like `temp <= 0 && measure.equals("C")` the condition `measure.equals("C")` will be always `false` because you **overwrite** the value of variable `measure` here:

```
if (measure.equals("C"))
   {measure = "Celsius";}
else 
   {measure = "Fahrenheit";}
```

Comment: Thanks!  For future improvement, would you suggest just adding (Celsius) behind the C in:System.out.print("Please enter the temperature measurement, C or F: "); or would there be a good way to add it in a similar way as above, but without wiping the value in if ((temp <= 0 && measure.equals("C")) || (temp <= 32 && !measure.equals("C")?

Comment: @mbnew I'd actually suggest breaking up your code into two parts: one for "F" and one for "C". The user is not going to change it while you're in the middle of those if statements, so you can save yourself having to check it multiple times.

Comment: @mbnew You can create separate variable which will be represent the meaning of the measure and will be used when you display a text only (in System.out.println("")).

Comment: Gotcha, so something similar to what gjman suggested at the bottom of this thread: ' if (measure.equals("F"))
                  { measurement = "Fahrenheit";}' and then splitting it up into the two different sections of code would be ideal?

Comment: @mbnew I would create ENUM {FREEZING, GAS, LIQUID} and enum constructor WaterType(String measure) and special method in enum object (maybe even by overriding toString method) to display text for user. For more simple use you could do as gjman said.

Comment: @Alex Didn't even know about ENUM, that's my experience level lol.  But I just read about it and that does look to be very fitting for what I'm doing.  Thanks so much for the advice, and I look forward to picking your brains again.  Hopefully much later :).

Answer (score 2):

Check your codes properly. You have initialized measure = "Celcius" if user input "C". So The value of measure is "Celcius" not "C".Declare another variable String measurement="Celcius";
Then in your if else statement:

```
 if (measure.equals("F"))
        { measurement = "Fahrenheit";}
```

Answer (score 1):

After the

```
 if ((temp <= 0 && measure.equals("C")) || (temp <= 32 && !measure.equals("C")))
    {
    System.out.print("The temperature is " + temp + " " + measure + ".  The water
    is freezing!");
    }
```

you must either put the other `if`s in an else, or use a `return` in order not to evaluate the next `if`s. If the temperature is less than  0 then it is also less than 100.

Comment: Well, that's not an issue if you are positive that you can only execute one of them. (i.e. if only one of the `if`s is ever true, then this suggested change won't do anything)

Comment: But if you have e. g `temp = -10`, then the first and second `if` clause are true, as - assuming measure being `"C"` - `-10 <= 0` and `-10 <= 100`.

Comment: True. (And this is what I get for typing without thinking enough. Sorry for the spam.)